# Regression analysis: conditional expectation value operator in the general equation, an abbreviation?

Tags: expectation, regression-analysis

A regression line can be stated as follows:

$E(Y|x) = a + x\beta$

where alpha and beta are constants. My question is, is this just some type of abbrevation as putting a number in place of x in the equation makes no sense. Instead it should be:

$E(Y|x=X) = a + x\beta $

Now by putting a number in place of x, the equation actually makes sense:

$E(Y|x=2) = \alpha + 2 \beta $

In contrast to:

$E(Y|2) = \alpha + 2 \beta $

The two refers to nothing.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of shorthand, as you describe.  People often interchangably refer to regression equations and regression functions.  As a regression function, the notation has a more straightforward interpretation.

Comment: The two notations $E(Y|X) = a + \beta X$ and $E(Y|X=x) = a + \beta x$ are correct.

Comment: @Paul But shouldn't a function be $E(Y(x))$?